# How to convert the pdf (images slightly distorted) of a book to a clearpdf/epub?

Tags: epub, image

Can someone please suggest a way to convert the pdf of a book which is collection of photos of the book into a clear pdf/epub.

I have attached a sample page for your reference, and pages like these needs to be converted into a clear pdf/epub.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to convert a poorly photographed document into a more uesful and pleasing appearance:

- Optical Character Recognition (OCR): Convert the image to text using OCR software, either [online](https://www.how2shout.com/tools/8-free-best-online-ocr-websites-to-extract-text-from-images.html) or with OS-specific tools, such as [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/download.html) for Windows OS or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/freeocr/). OCR is somewhat labor intensive, because even the best software does not always produce *verbatim* text, nor does OCR capture formatting, such as font style. However, OCR produces the *best* results, when the output is carefully edited in a word processor such as LibreOffice Writer or MS Word. The resulting document is readable at *any* size and is *searchable*.
- Image Editing: Edit each image and insert each into a new document, This is a quicker process, where the editor just trims each image to size and adjusts color and contrast appropriately. However, the final document is *not* searchable and can be magnified only a limited amount. Removing distortion of bent or wrinkled pages might not be feasible. Software to edit images ranges from costly [Adobe Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) to free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/).